# Find the least number of bills required to pay for a certain amount

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a game and I need a payment algorithm for the following scenario:

1- Suppose the money bills in the game are: 10,5,4,3,2,1

2- AI needs to choose the least number of bills needed to cover the exact amount,i.e if the required to pay is 8 and AI has (4,4,3,3,2)...He can choose (4,4) but not (3,3,2)

3- In case AI can't make the exact amount using the bills he has, he should choose the combination such that it gives the amount with the least difference value, i.e. if the required amount to pay is 7 and the AI has the following bills ( 10,5,4,4), he choses (4,4)  which gives the player 1 more above the needed amount.

I am stuck in implementing this in C#. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thank you!⁠

Comment: @BeyelerStudios The one you linked is with coins! This one with bills! ;P

Comment: Besides the coin/bills difference, in my case, i have a finite amount of bill, second I need to pay extra if exact amount wasn't possible...Please re-read again :)

Comment: Please show where you got stuck. Please show what you've tried. This looks like homework and it looks like you are asking people on SO to solve the task FOR you. I can't see any serious effort from your side.

Comment: It's still the knapsack problem, finite or non-finite, please come back once you're stuck on a specific question